# What to do with a tag that's to the point but never used

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Just an example, on Stack Overflow there are multiple questions each day about converting SQL to LINQ. Only a small fraction of them (38 currently) are tagged by [sql-to-linq-conversion](/questions/tagged/sql-to-linq-conversion).

The tag as such is to the point but what's the point when hardly anybody uses it?

Is it justified to (request to) remove such tags?

Comment: Low usage doesn't mean that the tag should be removed. We want the tag if it helps tell something about the content of the question.

Comment: It would be nice if questions are edited so that they get tagged under the correct tag(s) instead of removing to-the-point tags.

Comment: So you're saying there are questions which should use the tag but don't? Then edit the question.

Comment: @AzizShaikh, Bart, I though of that, but this is a hopeless task (in this specific case, but probably generally so).

Comment: @GertArnold For the backlog of content perhaps. But if it's a valid tag, start using it when you see a question that would benefit from it.

Comment: @GertArnold you are right but don't give up :) Other community members are also putting in their efforts for tag cleanups.

Comment: @Bart Even then... I can (and will) do my share, but I can cover only a slightly greater fraction.

Comment: @GertArnold Deserts are made of grains of sand, oceans of drops of water.....yada yada philosophical nonsense.... the only way to improve the usage of a valid tag is to actually start using it

Comment: @Bart OK, thanks. If this is the consensus this probably should be an answer and I know not to do useless burninate requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a tag is valid, and it applies to more than a single question, there is no reason to remove it. 38 questions is not a whole lot, but it certainly is enough for a tag to exist.

If the problem is that there are more than enough questions which could use the tag, but users are not using it, then start using it. Edit the questions so they use the tag. Especially the new ones. Who knows, users might just pick up on it.

Comment: Noted. And started :)